# When adding a property to an interface in C#, is that consider major, minor, or patch using semantic versioning?

Tags: c#, version-control, interfaces, properties

My team and I are trying to follow semantic versioning 2.0.0 to keep tabs on our library versions. We primarily use C# for our development and are currently in a situation where we are going to add a property to one of our interfaces.

We are a little unsure how this influences the rest of our applications that use this library. In my mind, I am thinking that this is not a *major* revision because we are adding functionality so the library should be backward compatible with any applications using an older version of the library right? On the other hand, this is not a bug fix so it's not considered a *patch*. The only thing left would be a *minor* revision. As a person who's never used semantic versioning 2.0.0, am I correct in thinking that this would be a *minor* revision?

Comment: It's not backwards compatible if consumers implement the interface.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Right, so I have several concretes (in separate libraries) that implement this interface... I had my doubts, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not backwards compatible if consumers of the library implement the interface, since they'd need to implement the new property. Thus, unless your documentation forbids them from doing so, it's a breaking change. Since it's a breaking change and you're past `1.0`, you need to increment the major version if you want to follow semantic versioning.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I failed to consider what would happen to libraries with concretes that consume the interface, and only thought about the applications that rely on it.

Comment: "Thus, unless your documentation forbids them from doing so, it's a breaking change". I disagree with this bit. If I'm not to use an interface, don't expose it as public. Weasel words in a document somewhere do not override this :)

Comment: @DavidArno In this case you're allowed to consume the interface, but not implement it. The C# type system isn't powerful enough to enforce every possible contract. Just like a sorting function might require the caller to pass in a consistent comparer function. If the depending code violates my contract, all bets are off (including compatibility).

Comment: All of the comments here make sense, but I do agree with @DavidArno in not seeing what some document has anything to do with the situation and how it could override any contract created by an interface regardless of the language used.

Comment: @StevieV A breaking change is a change that breaks the *contract* of a previous version. Some parts of that contract may be compiler or runtime enforced. But if those are infeasible, you can write a contract in prose as well. Pretty much *any* change will break a sufficiently brittle consumer. If the libraries documentation forbids a consumer from doing something, it's their own fault if something breaks when they do that.

Comment: That's a nice point thanks. In this question I am only considering the situation where we've already decided to add the property and that existing consumers would need to implement it.